# using pylab or matplotlib to display an image from file

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, computer-vision

When I try the following code, I get a picture of lena displayed on x and y axes, just fine:

```
import numpy
import pylab as lib
from PIL import Image  
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer
from scipy import misc

pl.imshow(misc.lena(),cmap=pl.gray())
pl.show()
```

But when I read in and then try to display my own image from file, like this:

```
image1 = color.rgb2gray(io.imread("PATH_TO_IMAGE\\akaria1.jpg"))
pl.imshow(Image.fromarray(image1),cmap=pl.gray())
pl.show()
```

then I do get the axes and everything, but in place of the image, just blackness taking up the space on the axes. Screenshot below:
[image]

However, I do know that I've read my image in fine, because when I do this:

```
image1 = color.rgb2gray(io.imread("C:\\work_asaaki\\caltech\\cars_brad\\akaria1.jpg"))
iv = ImageViewer(image1)
iv.show()
```

then I do get the image displayed in ImageViewer.

But what's the problem in the previous block of code? How can I get `pylab` to display my own image files just like it does lena? I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: did you try this: `pl.imshow(image1, cmap=pl.gray())`?

Comment: yes I did, but the output was the same.

Comment: Okay I did think I'd already tried what you said, but I must have tried it wrong. Because now when I try it again, it's working! You can put that as the answer then.

Comment: ok, I've posted the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
pl.imshow(image1, cmap=pl.gray())
```